# Generating MySQL table and columns automatically from JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to read JSON I have retrieved from an API.  I want to take that data and automatically create the table and columns needed to store the received information.  I don't want to statically make the columns because each coin I run this own may have more or less information.

My code below currently will only create 3 columns (id, name, and tickers) and insert data into id and name.
It will not make it past the first array of information.
Secondly, I get an error at `'$qi .= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "',";'`
`Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given` which I do not know how to fix.

## Original Code

```
$apiurl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/infocoin/tickers";
$json = file_get_contents($apiurl);

    JSON_to_table($json);

            function JSON_to_table($json, $tblName = "New_JSON_table_"){
    $conn = mysqli_connect($GLOBALS["db"]["host"], $GLOBALS["db"]["user"], $GLOBALS["db"]["pass"], $GLOBALS["db"]["name"]);
            $j_obj = json_decode($json, true);
        //$j_obj2 = $j_obj["tickers"];
        //var_dump($j_obj);
    print_r ($j_obj);
            if(!mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tblName . "'"))){ 
                $cq = "CREATE TABLE ". $tblName ." (
                id1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $cq .= $j_arr_key . " VARCHAR(256),";
                
        }
                $cq = substr_replace($cq,"",-1);
                $cq .= ")";
                mysqli_query($conn,$cq) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            }

            $qi = "REPLACE INTO $tblName (";
            reset($j_obj);
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $qi .= $j_arr_key . ",";
                }
                $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
            $qi .= ") VALUES (";
            next($j_obj);
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $qi .= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "',";
            $qi .= "'" .$value . "',";
                }
            $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
            $qi .= ")";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qi) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        return true;
```

## Code that gives duplicate column name error

```
$apiurl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/infocoin/tickers";
$json = file_get_contents($apiurl);

    JSON_to_table($json);

            function JSON_to_table($json, $tblName = "New_JSON_table_"){
    $conn = mysqli_connect($GLOBALS["db"]["host"], $GLOBALS["db"]["user"], $GLOBALS["db"]["pass"], $GLOBALS["db"]["name"]);
            $j_obj = json_decode($json, true);
        //$j_obj2 = $j_obj["tickers"];
        //var_dump($j_obj);
    print_r ($j_obj);
            if(!mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tblName . "'"))){ 
                $cq = "CREATE TABLE ". $tblName ." (
                id1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $cq .= $j_arr_key . " VARCHAR(256),";
                
        }
        next($j_obj);
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $cq .= $j_arr_key . " VARCHAR(256),";
                
        }
                $cq = substr_replace($cq,"",-1);
                $cq .= ")";
                mysqli_query($conn,$cq) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            }

            $qi = "REPLACE INTO $tblName (";
            reset($j_obj);
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $qi .= $j_arr_key . ",";
                }
                $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
            $qi .= ") VALUES (";
            next($j_obj);
                foreach($j_obj as $j_arr_key => $value){
                    $qi .= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "',";
            $qi .= "'" .$value . "',";
                }
            $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
            $qi .= ")";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qi) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        return true;
```

I have adjusted the code in multiple ways.  I have finally made it insert all the data from the second array into the 'tickers' column but I don't want that.  I have gotten the code to almost add the remaining column names but it then gives me an error `Duplicate column name 'name'`

## Edited Code From Comments Below

```
    $apiurl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/infocoin/tickers";
    $json = file_get_contents($apiurl);
    
        JSON_to_table($json);
    
                function JSON_to_table($json, $tblName = "New_JSON_table_"){
        $conn = mysqli_connect($GLOBALS["db"]["host"], $GLOBALS["db"]["user"], $GLOBALS["db"]["pass"], $GLOBALS["db"]["name"]);
                $j_obj = json_decode($json, true);
            //$j_obj2 = $j_obj["tickers"];
            //var_dump($j_obj);
        print_r ($j_obj);
                if(!mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $tblName . "'"))){ 
                    $cq = "CREATE TABLE ". $tblName ." (
                    id1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,";
                    foreach($j_obj["tickers"][0] as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $cq .= $j_arr_key . " VARCHAR(256),";
    
            }
                    $cq = substr_replace($cq,"",-1);
                    $cq .= ")";
                    mysqli_query($conn,$cq) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                }
    
                $qi = "REPLACE INTO $tblName (";
                reset($j_obj["tickers"][0]);
                    foreach($j_obj["tickers"][0] as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $qi .= $j_arr_key . ",";
                    }
                    $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
                $qi .= ") VALUES (";
                next($j_obj);
                    foreach($j_obj["tickers"][0] as $j_arr_key => $value){
                        $qi .= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $value) . "',";
                $qi .= "'" .$value . "',";
                    }
                $qi = substr_replace($qi,"",-1);
                $qi .= ")";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qi) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    
            return true;
```

## Errors From Updated Code

```
        Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 86
    
        Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 87
    
         Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 86
    
        Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 87
    
        Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 86
    
        Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/exp/coingecko_testmarket.php on line 87
       Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that data in this json is stored as multi-level structure (objects that contains another objects) that you can't store it in SQL database as it is.

You should generate 'create table' query for first item from 'tickers array `$j_obj['tickers'][0]` and then create 'insert' query for each element of that array, but you still have values that are not simple strings so you need to convert it.

Comment: I don't fully understand how to do it all. I've edit my code and get a few errors. I'll post my edited code and new errors above for you to see. Thanks for help.

Comment: I actually got your code working now. It's inserting the first array because of the specified [0].  How could I make it loop through each array getting the information but still only replace the data vs inserting new rows each time?